# Calculating towards a predefined percentage

Tags: linear-algebra

Couple of years ago I got great help here so I want to try again. The question is very similar.
It's probably yet again an easy question.

Let's say:

- INVENTORY: Jim currently has 10 apples, Sam has 30 apples, Alex has 50 apples, Jane has 10 apples.
- PRE-DEFINED PERCENTAGE: In an ideal situation, I want Jim to have 25% of all (100%) apples, Sam 35%, Alex 30%, Jane 10%.

Now I want to divide 50 new apples. Where should they go?

I want to divide the 50 apples to get closer to the actual pre-defined percentages in a fair way.

Note: Nobody can hand in their apples/give them to another.

Comment: Let's start with what we have and what the ideal situation would be. In total, have 150 apples. When distributed with the ideal percentages, that means that Jim would have 37.5 apples, Sam would have 52.5 apples, Alex would have 45 apples and Jane would have 15 apples. We see that Alex already has too many apples, compared to the ideal situation. Is he willing to give any of them away? If not, we can exclude him from the current dealing of the 50 additional apples. Since Jim is the furthest away from the ideal situation, we can immediately give him about 27 apples. Then 22 apples to Sam ...

Comment: Hi Matti. Thanks for your answer, I have edited the OP with the note that people are not able to give the current apples they have away. I can follow your approach, however I want to solve it mathematical and fair for everybody. This way if you give all the apples straight to Jim because he is the furthest away (from the ideal situation) you are not taking into account the other. I want all percentages to come closer to the pre-defined percentage every time I divide new apples, not work from top-down if you understand what I mean.